# Телеграм бот не отвечает

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telegram-bot, бот, c#-8.0

Бот не выводит сообщения в консоль и в телеграм.

```cs
using Telegram.Bot;

namespace TelegramBot
{
    class Program
    {
        static TelegramBotClient Bot;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bot = new TelegramBotClient("1208258758:AAF5yyhwf4Yd1g6G7_h93q_94efn8T_ATWw");

            Bot.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;

            Bot.StartReceiving();
            Console.ReadLine();
            Bot.StopReceiving();
        }

        private static void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            var massege = e.Message;

            Console.WriteLine(massege.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю спецификации этого бота, но предположу, что событие не срабатывает, потому что текущий поток приложения занят ожиданием ввода в консоли. То есть, пока работает `Console.ReadLine()`, больше ничего одновременно происходить не может. Попробуйте переделать на асинхронное ожидание.

Кстати, `ReadLine()` ждет нажатия Enter, можно сделать, чтобы завершалось при нажатии на любую клавишу, заменив его на `ReadKey()`.

Переделайте `Main` на `async`.

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Bot = new TelegramBotClient("1208258758:AAF5yyhwf4Yd1g6G7_h93q_94efn8T_ATWw");
    Bot.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;

    Bot.StartReceiving();
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
    });
    Bot.StopReceiving();
}
```